# Can you get all the Uprising achievements in the All Heroes mode?

Tags: overwatch

With the Uprising update, we got a set of new achievements to realize: Distinguished Service, Handle With Care, Mission Complete, Replacements, Strike Team and Unit Commendation. It is only mentionned in the Replacements achievement that you need to go in the All Heroes mode of Uprising to unlock it.

Is it possible to unlock the other achievements if you only go in the All Heroes mode, or do you need to do all of those in the normal Uprising mode?

Comment: OK, I messed up that last comment.  The 80% achievement (Handle With Care?) doesn't unlock in All Heroes Mode.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Replacements is the only Uprising achievement that you can get in All Heroes mode, and just to be clear, all 8 heroes have to be done in All Heroes mode. You can't do 4 in the regular mode and then 4 more in All Heroes.

Comment: OK, so if I do Mercy (one of the 4 heroes in normal mode) in All Heroes mode, does that count for Replacements?

Comment: I can't say specifically for Mercy, but it should, yes. I know Reinhardt counted for me. You just can't do it in Normal mode and have it count as a win in All Heroes mode.